# Jekyll - page.categories prints categories without spaces between them

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I'm using the following code to add classes to the page header that correspond with the post categories, or alternatively a custom variable called `imgclass` that I'm using to set a custom header image on some posts:

```
<header class="page-header {% if page.imgclass %}{{ page.imgclass }} {% else %}{{ page.categories }} {% endif %}">
  <p>some stuff</p>
</header>
```

The problem is that after running `jekyll build` it's outputting categories with no space between them. Where the categories are `cat1` and `cat2` jekyll will output:

```
<header class="page-header cat1cat2">
  <p>some stuff</p>
</header>
```

Why is this happening and how do I resolve?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's happening because `post.categories` is an array and liquid is basically just `#to_s`'ing it. You probably want `{{ post.categories | join: ' ' }}`.